# Use writeUTF and readUTF for http requests in Java

Tags: java, sockets, networking

This is a a Java method that tries to crawl a designated web page. I am using writeUTF and readUTF for socket communications to a server.

```
static void get_html(String host, String page, int port) throws IOException {
        Socket sock = new Socket(host, port);
        String msg = MessageFormat.format("GET {0} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {1}\r\n\r\n", page, host);

        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream inFromServer = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        String outMsg;

        while ((outMsg = buf.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Sending message: " + outMsg);
            outToServer.writeUTF(outMsg);

            String inMsg;
            try {
                inMsg = inFromServer.readUTF();
            } catch (EOFException eof) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(inMsg);
        }
        sock.close();
    }
```

The reason I am writing it this way was to mimic the `c` code, where you have a while loop of `send()` making all deliveries from a buffer, and another while loop of `recv()` from a buffer untill it hits 'null'. When execute my code, it just hangs there, I suspect that is due to a call of readUTF before I finished sending all my messages. If this is the case, is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this. HTTP is defined as text lines. `writeUTF()` does not write text, it writes a special format starting with a 16-bit binary length word. Similarly the HTTP server won't reply with that format into your `readUTF()` call. See the Javadoc.

You have to use binary streams and the `write()` method, with `\r\n` as the line terminator. Depending on the output format you may or may not be able to use `readLine()`. Best not, then you don't have to write two pieces of code: use binary streams again.

In fact you should throw it all away and use `HttpURLConnection`. Implementing HTTP is not as simple as may hastily be supposed.